# Parse.com atomic safe approach to create PFObjects from iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, atomic

From an iOS app a logged in PFUser is able to create an object with class name "X".

**X** has a **name** attribute and in the whole system there can **only** be **one** X object with that name.

**Any** user on iOS can create an X object providing a name for it.

So I am trying to figure out HOW TO MAKE SURE THAT ONLY ONE X is created with a given "name" in the case where a bunch of users try to create at the same time that object on the server from the iOS app.

So how can I GUARANTEE that ONLY ONE X object is created on my parse.com system in the case where a bunch of users try to create the same object at THE SAME TIME from the iOS client?

Thank you

EDIT:
I am not handling any Cloud code. I want to know if this is possible using only iOS code.

Thank you

EDIT 2:
So, if from iOS this is not possible, then how would I achieve this using cloud code, could anybody give me a quick intro to solve this problem in cloudCode?

Comment: check docs on 'cloud code' and 'Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Review", function(request, response) {'    . Its like a DB Trigger and the error function you can use to alert the UI 'that value exists' .

Comment: Seems like there still isn't a way to do this??https://www.parse.com/questions/create-and-save-pfobject-if-it-does-not-exist-atomically